# jQuery sortable - Detect if item has moved up or down the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Wanted to know if there is anyway to detect if the item has moved up or down the list when you use jQuery sortable option.

I have this simple example below that shows an alert message when an item has moved. However I wanted to find out if the moved item has gone up or down the list.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    change: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Leg Moved.')
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
 #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; border:1px solid }
 #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are position and originalPosition values available in the stop,change function of the sortable. Both these contains the top,left values. You can compare the top values in originalPosition and position to know whether the item has moved up or down

**Reference:** https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            change: function(event, ui) {
                var movement = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top > 0 ? "down" : "up";
            }
        });
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to quite cover it, since ui.item.index() is 0 based when moving up and 1-based when moving down - and your direction of movement can change.  You can drag something up the list and then down a little and get a different base.  originalPosition is where you started, so you won't catch the difference.

Comment: This is what I've found - even doing parseInt on it, the top and left values change by 5 or 6 when you drag something away then return it to its original position (within the same drag event).  It's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

IF you need to know if a move was up or down in comparison with the previous change event, you could store the latest index (sequence number) as the sortable's data, and use it on the next change event for comparison, after which you update it again:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).data('idx', ui.item.index());
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      var idx = ui.placeholder.prevAll().filter(':not(.ui-sortable-helper)').length;
      // print relative change in index: negative is up, positive is down
      console.log(idx - $(this).data('idx')); 
      $(this).data('idx', idx);
    }
  });
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; border:1px solid }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```